# Angualrjs factor is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this js

```
var app = angular.module('MyApp', []);

app.factory('Data', function () {
    return {message: "I am data from a service"}
})

app.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope, Data) {
    $scope.data = Data;
})

app.controller('SecondCtrl', function ($scope) {

})
```

and this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>index</title>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/index.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


    <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="message"/>
        <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    </div>

    <div ng-controller="SecondCtrl" >
        <input type="text" ng-model="message"/>
        <h2>{{message}}</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

when I run the application, the message `I am data from a service` is not loaded into the `h2` of the first controller although I made the factory and passed it to the controller

Comment: You are assigning `$scope.data = Data`. Then you should access in the view `<h2>{{data.message}}</h2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning `$scope.data = Data`. Then you should access it in the view

```
<div ng-controller="FirstCtrl" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.message"/>
    <h2>{{data.message}}</h2>
 </div>
```